# PixiJs 4 rotation speed and determine stopping location/axis

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have started working with PixiJs to develop a simple game. I am trying to rotate a sprite based on a click of the button, and then allowing the user top stop the rotation with another button click.

What I am not able to achieve is determine how many "cycles" the rotation would have done, for example if the image did a full rotation 3, 4 times, and its stopping location determining how many remaining rotations are needed for another full cycle. Is there something in place to easily retrieve this?

The code I have so far is quite basic and simple:

```
    initGameLayout() {
        const top = new PIXI.Graphics();
        top.beginFill(0x2185c7);
        top.drawRect(0, 0, this.app.screen.width, this.margin);

        const headerStyle = new PIXI.TextStyle({
            fontSize: 24,
            fontStyle: 'italic',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        });

        const headerText = new PIXI.Text('', headerStyle);
        headerText.x = Math.round((top.width - headerText.width) / 2);
        headerText.y = Math.round((this.margin - headerText.height) / 2);
        top.addChild(headerText);

        const spinButton = new PIXI.Graphics();
        spinButton.beginFill(0x2185c7);
        spinButton.drawRect(0, 0, this.app.screen.width, this.margin);
        spinButton.width = 150;
        spinButton.height = 100;
        spinButton.x = 620
        spinButton.y = 500
        spinButton.buttonMode = true;
        spinButton.interactive = true;
        spinButton.on('pointerdown', this.spinWheel);

        const spinButton2 = new PIXI.Graphics();
        spinButton2.beginFill(0x2185c3);
        spinButton2.drawRect(0, 0, this.app.screen.width, this.margin);
        spinButton2.width = 150;
        spinButton2.height = 100;
        spinButton2.x = 420
        spinButton2.y = 500
        spinButton2.buttonMode = true;
        spinButton2.interactive = true;
        spinButton2.on('pointerdown', this.stopWheel);

        this.bunny = new PIXI.Sprite.from('https://pixijs.io/examples-v4/examples/assets/bunny.png');
        this.bunny.width = 50;
        this.bunny.height = 50;
        this.bunny.anchor.set(0.5);
        this.bunny.x = this.app.screen.width / 2;
        this.bunny.y = this.app.screen.height / 2;

        this.bunny.rotate += 0.1;

        this.app.stage.addChild(top);
        this.app.stage.addChild(spinButton);
        this.app.stage.addChild(spinButton2);
        this.app.stage.addChild(this.bunny);

    }

    spinWheel() {
        if (!this.running)
        {
            this.running = true;
            this.app.ticker.add((delta: any) => {
                this.bunny.rotation += 0.1;
            });
        } else {
            this.running = false;
            this.bunny.rotation -= -0.1;
        }

    }

    stopWheel() {
        this.bunny.rotation -= -0.1;
        this.running = false;
    }
```

Appreciate any help anyone could give on the above issue

-Jes

Answer (score 0):

The [`rotation`](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#rotation) member of a sprite is the measure of radians it is rotated. There are `2*Math.PI` [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) in a full circle. You can use this information to calculate the desired values:

1. When the sprite is first clicked, store `originalRotation = bunny.rotation;`
2. When the sprite is clicked again, calculate `angleRotated = Math.abs(bunny.rotation - originalRotation);`
3. Then `numCycles = Math.floor(angleRotated / (2*Math.PI));`
4. And `radiansUntilNextCycle = 2*Math.PI - (angleRotated % (2*Math.PI));`

If you are more familiar with degrees, you can use those instead. Swap:

- `bunny.rotation` with [`bunny.angle`](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#angle)
- `2*Math.PI` with `360`

---

I'm assuming by "cycle" you mean a single rotation of 360 degrees. However, your question is difficult to understand because each time you use the word "rotation" it seems to have a different meaning. So it doesn't quite make sense.

It may also help to explain *why* you want these values; what will you do with them?

And [pixiplayground.com](https://www.pixiplayground.com) is a great place to share live, functional code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I get your point, the angle is somewhat easier to understand. What I have in mind is to have a wheel rotate game, where each slice on the wheel would have a number. Assuming the wheel can have 8 different slices. The user chooses a number between 1 and 8, and will try stop the wheel on the number chosen. When the wheel stops spinning/rotating, I would need to check the "active slice" and see if the number on the slice matches the user's input. This is basically what I am trying to achieve.